# Entity Framework claims to save changes but sometimes doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a very strange problem - sometimes my database fails to populate with Plans and Buckets, then throws the exception shown at the end when trying to save Tasks to the db. Other times the code works perfectly. I would appreciate any insight into why this could be. Could it be a timing issue with the delete commands?

```
EntitiesModelContainer db = new EntitiesModelContainer();

List<Plan> ignoredPlans = db.Plans.Where(p => p.Ignore).ToList();

// Delete old data completely
// foreign keys will cascade delete some tables such as buckets and tasks
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Plans");
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Assignees");

PlansResponse plans = GraphAPI.GetPlans();
foreach (PlanResponse plan in plans.Plans)
{
    Plan planRecord = new Plan()
    {
        Id = plan.ID,
        Title = plan.Title,
        Ignore = ignoredPlans.Find(p => p.Id == plan.ID) != null
    };
    db.Plans.Add(planRecord);
    bool changes = db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
    int result = db.SaveChanges();

    if (!planRecord.Ignore)
    {
        BucketsResponse buckets = GraphAPI.GetBuckets(plan);
        foreach (BucketResponse bucket in buckets.Buckets)
        {
            Bucket bucketRecord = new Bucket()
            {
                Id = bucket.ID,
                Name = bucket.Name,
                PlanId = bucket.PlanID
            };
            db.Buckets.Add(bucketRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        TasksResponse tasks = GraphAPI.GetTasks(plan);
        foreach (TaskResponse task in tasks.Tasks)
        {
            Task taskRecord = new Task()
            {
                Id = task.ID,
                Title = task.Title,
                Progress = task.PercentComplete,
                Description = task.HasDescription ? GraphAPI.GetTaskDetails(task).Description : null,
                CreatedDateTime = task.CreatedDateTime,
                DueDateTime = task.DueDateTime,
                CompletedDateTime = task.CompletedDateTime,
                PlanId = task.PlanID,
                BucketId = task.BucketID
            };
            db.Tasks.Add(taskRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

The last line is where the error occurs.

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PlanTask". The conflict occurred in database "Dashboard-dev", table "dbo.Plans", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

The strange thing is, it doesn't always throw! Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**: You're right - it appears the code is running twice, concurrently. Why? I didn't (intentionally) mean to do this...

```
public class DBController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DBAccess.UpdateData();
        return View();
    }
}
```

The snippet posted above is the start of this method `UpdateData()`.

Comment: `db.Plans.Where(p => p.Ignore).ToList();` before deleting the existing records looks suspicious because the existing entity instances will remain tracked by the context (although in such case `db.Plans.Add(planRecord);
` should raise exception). Try using no tracking query, e.g. `db.Plans.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.Ignore).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's complaining about the foreign key PlanId (I'm guessing), I'd say GetTasks somehow returns an incorrect PlanId.

To get to the bottom of it I'd set up a profiler session and examine the SQL statements when there's an error. Or just examine the objects in the debugger when the exception happens, I guess. The values of the properties should give a clue as to what's going on.

Edit: I just noticed your first line says 'sometimes it fails to populate with plans and tasks', missed that. I don't understand how it would continue if it couldn't save a plan, but a SQL profiler session might be able to answer that.

Edit after the fact: of course the simplest answer could be concurrency, especially if this is a web application, two requests could be coming in at the same time and overlapping.

Comment: Yes, that's what's confusing me so much. From debugging I can see that the integer `result` returns `1`, indicating a plan should be added. However, the plan seems to remain in `db.Plans.Local` only in the case of an exception - sometimes this works, and it seems to work when I set a breakpoint to try debugging.

Comment: Note that an exception is not thrown, the code continues as if it had been successful. Maybe the DELETE overwrites it?

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where the deletes would be executed later than the adds. And it doesn't look like you're handling connection details or transactions manually, so that can't be it either. Maybe several threads or instances of the application execute this at the same time and they overlap? Either way it must be something external to this code, I think.

Comment: Hey, I posted an update to my question. The problem has been solved but I would appreciate if you could tell me why!

Comment: Ah I see it was a concurrency issue after all. If this is a web application then it's simple, there are two requests coming in at the same time :)

Comment: Why would this be the case? I'm using the chrome exe with browser link. Is there a request log I can access?

Comment: Aha! Turns out I was visiting the same URL so often Chrome was pre-loading the page as I typed the URL. The page was then loaded again when I hit enter. That's why it sometimes worked, sometimes it only loaded once! Thanks for your help! If you care to mention concurrency in your answer I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Can tasks have a null `PlanID` (why it might work sometimes)? The delete at the top looks suspicious, shouldn't you be setting the `PlanID` to the newly created `planRecord`? Either way you are setting it to a Plan that no longer exists so a cascade might not be working somewhere ( if for example it was supposed to nullify dead plans as foreign keys to `Task` and `Bucket`).

Comment: Plans will always have a valid ID - they come from Microsoft's Graph API, the Planner part.